# custom validator not showing errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation

I have an ASP.NET webform. All of my validators do their job except for the custom validator. As far as I know my code is correct but he doesn't show the errors. It seems like he doesn't call my javascript function or my code behind function.

here is my code

javascript

```
<%-- javascript--%>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function validateNaam(oSrc, args) {
        var voorNaam = document.getElementById("Voornaam");;
        var regex = /^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$/;

        if (voorNaam.match(regex)) {
            alert("Gelieve geen ongeldige tekens te gebruiken voor uw naam aub.");
            return false;
        }
    }

</script>
```

aps custom validator

```
 <%-- Gebruikersnaam label, textbox en validator --%>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email">Voornaam: </asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Voornaam" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Voornaam"
                                CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." />
                            <%-- Custom validator voor naam --%>
                            <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidatorGebruikersnaam" runat="server" 
                                CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="Uw naam bevat ongeldige tekens" 
                                ValidationGroup="AllValidators" OnServerValidate="CustomValidatorGebruikersnaam_ServerValidate"
                                ClientValidationFunction="validateNaam" ControlToValidate="Voornaam">!!</asp:CustomValidator>
```

and code behind

```
protected void CustomValidatorGebruikersnaam_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        args.IsValid = Validatie.ControleerNaam(args.Value.ToString());
    }
    catch 
    {

        args.IsValid = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a validation group on your custom validator.

The code for the button, which you have not posted must have no validation group on it.

Remove this ValidationGroup="AllValidators" and it should work.

Comment: I now get the text of the custom validator if it is wrong, but neither the error message or the javascript alert appear

Comment: Have you looked at the regex validator? I think you could use that instead. This article shows an example. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx

Comment: Really a big thanks to you! This did the trick. I know this was a very stupid mistake, overlooking that, but I am learning ASP since yesterday.